# how to extract SVG images/tables from Beamer multi-page PDF?

Tags: beamer, graphics, svg

I have a 50-page PDF from Beamer in which I found a typo that I need to correct before a job interview.  I no longer have access to the image files included via `includesvg` and table files included by `input`, so I can't re-compile the source code.

I have the source code, but not the files that were included.

I have tried `pdfimages` but this won't work for SVG, and will produce sloppy PNG for entire slides, not the images.

Is there a way to extract the SVG and tables so that I can edit the typo in the source code and get a PDF?

Comment: get yourself a pdf editor. I think foxit and pdfxchange have test versions. (Make a backup of the pdf first).

Comment: the svg would have been converted to pdf so the original svg is not there to be extracted. what might be possible is to extract the pdf from that part of the document and convert to svg, but this is generation of new svg not extracting the original

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Can you show exactly what typo you would like to fix, e.g. is it replacing one letter with another or something more complicated?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  all I need to do is change 2 words on 2 slides, but LibreOffice Draw changes the font, and makes the slides look really messy after I save it, the font is very different from the original PDF and I don't know why

Comment: Which OS do you use and can you show the exact words you'd like to exchange?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, the typo is "obestiy" which should be "obesity"

Comment: @con Ah, that's good. You might be able to directly edit that in the pdf. Make a copy first, so you still have a functioning copy of the pdf in case something goes wrong. Then have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109177/488245

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm having issues implementing that, the uncompressed/text PDF doesn't have the word that I need, and pdftk https://askubuntu.com/questions/803850/find-and-replace-with-on-pdf-file-from-command-line also failed, I'm going to have to make another question :/

Comment: Rename the PDF presentation to whatever (said `myfigures.pdf`)  an then in the source replace each \includesvg by some some like  `\includegraphics[trim=2cm 1cm 1cm 2cm,clip,page=3]{myfigures.pdf}`.